# #if field == req.locals.variable, render handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Here's the idea:

```
{#if creatorField == req.locals.user)
  <div class="thisHTML">{{ story }}</div>
{else}
  <div class="thatHTML">{{ story }}</div>
{/if}
```

If the creatorField does not match the req.locals.user value, then a different html template would render. Is there functionality for this built-in, or does it need some sort of helper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handlebars Helper for rendering template if the creatorField == req.locals.user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422333/handlebars-helper-for-rendering-template-if-the-creatorfield-req-locals-user)

Answer (score 1):

Logic should remain in your controller, so have the boolean result of `creatorField == req.locals.user` in your Handlebars context instead of computing it within the template, and then simply use the built-in [`if` block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#conditionals).